# multidimensional array with each to every connections

Tags: php, arrays

there is a multidimensional array like

> [­["14","16"],["26"],["24"],["5","8"]]

the length of the total array is not limited, nested will be an average of 1-3 elements
nested ones will always be numbers, not arrays, i.e. the array is two-dimensional. the task is to get a "each with each" relationship, i.e. I should get sets of the kind

> 14,26,24,5;
>   14,26,24,8;
>   16,26,24,5;
>   16,26,24,8;

I tried cycles, and tried recursion, but it doesn’t work.

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you made an attempt at solving this? If so, post a [mcve] showing where you got stuck, if you wouldn't mind. If not, I recommend making an attempt at solving it and showing what you've tried. See [ask] for guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = [
    [2, 4],
    [],
    [3, 6],
    [2, 3],
];

$output = array_reduce($data, function (array $carry = null, array $item = null): array {
    if (!$carry) {
        return $item;
    }

    if (!$item) {
        return $carry;
    }

    $output = [];
    foreach ($carry as $foo) {
        foreach ($item as $bar) {
            $output[] = $foo . '-' . $bar;
        }
    }

    return $output;
});

print_r($output);
```

---

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2-3-2
    [1] => 2-3-3
    [2] => 2-6-2
    [3] => 2-6-3
    [4] => 4-3-2
    [5] => 4-3-3
    [6] => 4-6-2
    [7] => 4-6-3
)
```